how do i put text (list) next to the image in a bootstrap card?
I am in dire need of help.  I built a site in Muse in 2016 and of course they shut it down but now even w the subscription i cant open my files so the last page i had to convert out is massive and has 120+ images w a small text list next to it.  i am using mostly bootstrap and html to try and remake this but i cannot seem to get the image and list next to each other.  after searching this place i found the below code but no matter how much i mess w it.  please help.  in the end each of these cards needs to link to a bio page.
so you can see what i am trying to recode:
this is the page i need to remake client list
<div class="card w-50">
    <div class="card-img-top d-flex align-items-center bg-light">
        <div>
            <img src="images/headshots/actor-Headshot.jpg" alt="actor headshot"        class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <div class="card-header">
            actor
        </div>
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Star Wars Saga</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Indiana Jones</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Blade Runner</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Witness</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Star Wars: The Force Awakens</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>


I'm assuming that you want to have the list that is on the right of the image so here may be what you need.
<div class="card">
  <div class="row g-0">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="images/headshots/actor-Headshot.jpg" alt="actor headshot">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card-header">
         Actor
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
           <li class="list-group-item">Star Wars Saga</li>
           <li class="list-group-item">Indiana Jones</li>
           <li class="list-group-item">Blade Runner</li>
           <li class="list-group-item">Witness</li>
           <li class="list-group-item">Star Wars: The Force Awakens</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

You may not need to use w-50, use col-12 col-md-6 instead. So that you will have a full-width card on mobile and a half-width card on other screensizes.
Hope it helps ;)
